# Can data saved on a local device with Hive be moved to another device by backup of mobile device?(Flutter)

Tags: android, ios, flutter

If I actually try it, the answer will come out, but I don't have multiple actual smartphones, so let me ask you a question for the time being.

I am making a learning support app with Flutter. We use Hive to save the user's learning progress on the user's device.

I am making a learning support app with Flutter. We use Hive to save the user's learning progress on the user's device.

With this alone, if the user's device is damaged or lost, the progress data will be lost at that point.
Therefore, in preparation for that, I feel the need to implement a mechanism to output the same data stored locally to other data storage services such as calendar and iCloud.

However, I think that contact information etc. can be restored to a new device by backing up the device data for both iPhone and android smartphone, but can the data saved using Hive be restored (moved)?

If the Hive data is automatically backed up when the user backs up the data on their device and the user can access that data from my app on the new device, I don't think it is necessary to implement backup functionality myself.

Also, even if the above solution is possible, is the above solution effective only when replacing iPhone → iPhone or Android smartphone → Android smartphone?